# value is undefined from exporting object in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my app.js file I have I am exporting an object with properties and values. On the route, I am including the file but I am getting the value as undefined. If I don't pass in the argument "users" in the createUser function it returns the value as undefined. If I pass in the argument, the server crashes and says it cannot get the .id of undefined. My goal is to have the value increment by 1 when the path is reached.

My app.js file:

```
exports.users = {
    id : 1,
    room : 0
};
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var enter = require('./routes/enter');
var chat = require('./routes/chat');
var room = require('./routes/room');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var update = require('./routes/update');


app.use('/room', room);
app.use('/user', user);
app.use('/enter', enter);
app.use('/chat', chat);
app.use('/update', update);
app.use(express.static('public/dist'));
app.use(express.static('public/js'));
app.use(express.static('public/dist/images'));
app.use(express.static('bower_components'));

app.listen(1337);
```

---

My user file:

```
var express = require('express');
var user = express.Router();
var room = require('./room.js');
var users = require('../app.js').users;


user.get('/', function(req, res) {

    createUser();
    res.send(users.id.toString());
});

function createUser(){
    users.id = users.id + 1;
    console.log(user.id + ' this is the user.id');
    return users;
}
module.exports = user;
```

Comment: If you haven't already, you should read how Node.js handles [Cycles](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles) or circular dependencies (in this case, `app -> routes/user -> app -> ...`). You may consider moving the definition of `users` to its own module/file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var users = {
    id : 1,
    room : 0
 };
 exports.users = users;
```

simple curiosity, but what happen if you try like this ?

---

To byPass your problem

```js
var express = require('express');
var user = express.Router();
var room = require('./room.js');
//var users = require('../app.js').users;
var users = {
  id : 1,
  room : 0
};

user.get('/', function(req, res) {

    createUser();
    res.send(users.id.toString());
});

function createUser(){
    users.id = users.id + 1;
    console.log(user.id + ' this is the user.id');
    return users;
}
module.exports = user;
```

You don't seem to need `Users` outside this module, so you can create it with the 'user' module.

```
users.id = users.id + 1;
```

It will always be incremented like you want !

Comment: I get the exact same response.

Comment: if you try to log `console.log(users)` after `var users = require('../app.js').users;` have you got something ?
`

Comment: I have just made some modifications to my answer, just check it and tell me.